# Implementing RecyclerView with collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement RecyclerView with collapsing toolbar,but i'm facing the problem as RecyclerView comes upward on collapsing toolbar.What i want to acheive that it should be down and comes up with collapsing toolbar.
please help? Below is the image what i'm currently getting the result.

[image]

here my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="sccs.android.com.userinformation.HomeScreen">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@mipmap/nature2"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @shijil showed.

You need to add this attribute to the RecyclerView (or any frame you want to have as the parent in your content):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

This would be your RecyclerView's code (You don't need to add anything else besides the `app:layout_behavior` attribute):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="325dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@mipmap/nature2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_flexible_space"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: hey thanks @Shijil it work,but i got problem in scrolling up and down with collapsing toolbar,its very slow i tried scollview but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="sccs.android.com.userinformation.HomeScreen">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@mipmap/nature2"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Zeeshan, I tried your code and it didn't work, it is still showing the frame above the toolbar, plus you are missing the opening `CoordinatorLayout` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The  `Toolbar` widget should be the last child of the  `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in order